# Estimating Distance From an Image

Tags: 3d, camera, geometry, distance, photogrammetry

Assuming that the person stands parallel to a wall. The person and the wall are at the same ground level. The person takes a picture of the wall (Considering that the person always captures the bottom edge of the wall).

**Hypothesis:**

It is obvious that when the person is closer to the wall, the bottom edge of the wall tends to be at the bottom in the image. As we move farther, the edge moves more closer towards the center in the image.

So, there exists a relationship between "Distance from wall" and "Position of edge of the wall in the image".

**The known parameters are:**

-> Height of the camera from which the image is captured

-> Angle(Orientation of the camera)

-> Position of the edge in the image

How can I formulate the distance(depth) based on the above parameters? Are there any other parameters that affect the above relationship?

Comment: You need also camera vertical resolution and vertical angle of view

Comment: Field of View? Yes it is known

Answer (score 0):

vres is vertical resolution (for example, 1080). 
vfov - vertical field of view (for example, 20 degrees)
f - focal distance (deduced from fov)

```
 vres/2 / f = tg(vfov/2)
 1/f = 2 * tg(vfov/2) / vres
```

dy - position of bottom edge at image relative to matrix center
theta - angle of edge relative to objective axis

```
 tg(theta) = dy / f = dy * 2 * tg(vfov/2) / vres
 theta = atan(dy / f = dy * 2 * tg(vfov/2) / vres)
```

fi is camera pitch angle
alpha is inclination of camera relative to wall bottom

```
alpha = fi +/- theta   (depending on pitch sign)
```

d is distance wall bottom- camera bottom
h is camera height

```
d = h * ctg(alpha)
```

Comment: What do tg, ctg and "objective axis" mean? Tan, Cot??

Comment: tangent, contangent, camera direction